# Can't get codepon accordion css-only code to work

Tags: css, codepen

I'm trying to replicate the css-only accordion solution from codepen found here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmGYbP

However, when I copy the code into jsfiddle, it doesnt work and I notice code in the CSS missing that the HTML refers to.

(1) Does anyone understand how access the full code needed for this solution?

(2) The first section is always collapsed when loading, is there a way to keep all closed at outset until clicked?

This is what I can get:

```
HTML and CSS code below:
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
.panel-title > a:before {
    float: right !important;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f068";
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.panel-title > a.collapsed:before {
    float: right !important;
    content:"\f067";
}
.panel-title > a:hover, 
.panel-title > a:active, 
.panel-title > a:focus  {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.le VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a css only approach in the codepen even though the title says so.  If you click on the settings tab in codepen you can see that they are loading jquery and bootstrap under the javascript tab.  This accordion functionality is part bootstrap.  So if you want it to work you will have to load bootstraps css and javascript along with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on the gear icon in the "CSS" section of codepen. IN here you will see that "Bootstraps" Css library is linked. This is why the html contains classes for the missing css.

Additionally bootstrap javascript is being loaded in the JS section. Under the gear icon. **So you are not getting a CSS only solution by using this method/code anyways**.

[image]

Comment: Re: your question on your post. It got voted down because JS syntax errors are pretty easy to search. Also, in general, it's a good idea to write a smaller amount of code to see if what you're doing works rather than a bunch of code with the same error--work one chunk at a time. If a single downvote causes you to "hate the site" then it may not be the site for you--nothing wrong with that. SO *does* put some responsibility on people that asks questions, and not everybody can deal with that.